# How to pass loop variable as input to cut?

Tags: bash

I have a tab separated `file`:

```
  c1    1000000
  c2    2000000
  c3    1000000
```

I would like to loop through each line of that file and save the second column in a variable to then loop through increments of that number and generate a specific new file out of it.

```
    out=""
    while read i; do
      length=$(echo $i | cut -d$'\t' -f2) #How to use $i here?
      c=$(echo $i | cut -d$'\t' -f1)
      start=1
      end=10000
      for (( i = 0; i < $(expr $length / 500); i++ )); do
        start=$(expr $start + $i \* 500)
        end=$(expr $end + $i \* 500)
        echo $c $start $end >> out
      done
    done <file
```

Of course, I am always happy to learn about how inefficient my code may be and how I can improve it.

Thanks for your input!

Comment: `expr` is a crazy-inefficient artifact from the 1970s; invoking an external program any time you want to do simple integer calculation is orders of magnitude slower than doing that work in-process. The 1992 POSIX sh standard requires shells to support built-in math; you should use that instead. `start=$(( start + i * 500 ))`

Comment: Also, much, **much** more efficient to not use `cut` at all. `while IFS=$'\t' read -r c length; do ...` will split your line into two variables, `c` and `length`, with no extra process needed.

Comment: Also, using `>> out` inside an inner loop costs you a lot of performance -- move it to the outer `done` where you have the `<file` and that way you only open your output file *once*, rather than re-opening it every time you want to `echo` a single line into it.

Comment: Oh. Actually, the main reason `echo $i | cut ...` doesn't work the way you want is because the lack of quotes causes the tab to be replaced with a space. It would need to be `echo "$i" | cut ...` (but don't do that for the reasons given above -- use `IFS=$'\t' read` instead).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem isn't specific to loops -- it's specific to unquoted `echo`s. As described in [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo), `echo $i` string-splits and glob-expands the contents of `$i` before passing them to `echo`.

Part of string-splitting is that the content are split into words, and the words are passed as separate parameters -- so what it actually runs is `echo "c1" "1000000"`, which doesn't put a tab between the two values, so your `cut` command can't find a tab to cut on.

The Right Way to fix this is to not use `cut` at all:

```
while IFS=$'\t' read -r c length; do
```

Comment: Not the first time you solved one of my problems. Thank you so much!